# Firebase SDK Admin setCredentials other than static JSON file

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I've been playing around with Google's Firebase Admin SDK and while I have configured and created the client I need to push notifications around, the way the credentials for the FCM project are set does not satisfy me.

For the time being, I'm setting up my project's credentials using the provided JSON file, that is currently stored within the filesystem of my server and retrieved as shown in the relevant docs:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();
```

While this works fine for the most part, it does put an extra load maintenance wise as well as a another point of failure (e.g. someone deleting the credential file by mistaken).

From the docs I'm seeing that SDK intended for NodeJs allows for setting the project related credentials ad hoc, meaning that there is no need for the JSON file to be present. Also the docs seem to mention that the authentication can happen with other means (but they do not elaborate more) as can  be seen by this relevant line:

`The Admin SDKs can alternatively be authenticated with a different credential type`

Mind you that this almost certainly is about the Google Cloud Platform but it seems to leave a Window open hinting that this can also occur for other versions of the SDK.

Now my question is the following. Suppose that I do not want to make do with the credentials store on the JSON file which is in turned stored in the filesystem, is there another way for the Java SDK to retrieve them?

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: The [`GoogleCredential` Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential) shows several ways of creating credentials with its builder, and you could also use many different implementations of `InputStream` in your code. You aren't limited to a `FileInputStream` by the API.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)](http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.9.0/apidocs/index.html) isn't actually reading from a File.  It's reading from an InputStream.  That InputStream happens to be a FileInputStream in your code.

You can use any InputStream that will feed your code the credentials you're looking for, so you have as many options as there are types of streams to be the source of your data.

Only you know what your real options are, as those of us reading the question aren't familiar with your runtime environment or how you package your code.  But I'm sure you have a lot of flexibility here.

Comment: Sure enough you're right on that and it might so be that my phrasing in the question is not entirely correct. Let me rephrase that then. I do understand that I can use whatever InputStream I like for example I was thinking of storing them in the db and retrieving them from there. My main question is, that is there any way to retrieve them ad hoc from Google by providing say the related project's account credentials?

Comment: No. You can think of the credentials like a password.  Having an API to retrieve a password opens the door to all kinds of security problems.  Or, having a password to get another, more secure password seems like a problem too.  You need to provide the "password" at the time of use.